# Drawing using matplotlib in pysimplegui

Tags: python, matplotlib, pysimplegui

How can i clean up previous drawing before drawing again with matplotlib in PySimpleGui?

I wanted to draw a bar chart which i could be able to draw but not able to delete using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import random

layout=[[sg.B('Draw'),sg.B('Delete')],[sg.Canvas(key='canvas1')]]

window=sg.Window("Test", layout)

def draw_figure(canvas, figure):
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().forget()
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    return figure_canvas_agg

def drawBars(x_data,y_data,barColor,legend):
    plt.cla()
    p1 = plt.bar(x_data, y_data, width=0.9, color=barColor)
    plt.legend((p1[0],), (legend,))
    plt.tight_layout()
    fig = plt.gcf()
    return fig

l=range(1,10)
y_data=list(l)
x_data=list(random.sample(l,len(l)))

while True:
    event, value = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'Draw':
        draw_figure(window['canvas1'].TKCanvas, drawBars(x_data,y_data,'red','plot'))
    if event == 'Delete':
        pass
        #what code i should here to do the job?
window.close()
```

Are there any functions that i can call to clean up any previous drawings? Can someone please helpme with it, i was looking for it for really really long time in google, all i found are some related codes [1] that didn't work well with me, i couldn't find a simple and clean one. Thank you guys.

[1]https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Matplotlib_Browser.py

Comment: You can use `plt.clf()` to clear the current figure.

Comment: @Fastnlight you mean i should add this line at the begining of my drawBars functions? I tried but it didn't work as well

Comment: `plt.clf()` clears the current figure. If you want to clear everything, use `plt.cla()`

Comment: @Fastnlight its not working as well..

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Community its 200 lines less than the original code

Comment: Try this for the delete section: `window['canvas1'].TKCanvas.delete("all")`

Comment: @Fastnlight sorry it's not working also  :< :<, it didn't give any errors and didn't work

Comment: @Fastnlight No that was good, i exchanged the  .clear() attribute with .get_tk_widget().forget() and it worked! Thank you so much! repost your answer again please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put your code into OpenAI's Codex, and this is what I got back:

### Code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import random

layout=[[sg.B('Draw'),sg.B('Delete')],[sg.Canvas(key='canvas1')]]

window=sg.Window("Test", layout)

def draw_figure(canvas, figure):
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().forget()
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    return figure_canvas_agg

def drawBars(x_data,y_data,barColor,legend):
    plt.cla()
    p1 = plt.bar(x_data, y_data, width=0.9, color=barColor)
    plt.legend((p1[0],), (legend,))
    plt.tight_layout()
    fig = plt.gcf()
    return fig

l=range(1,10)
y_data=list(l)
x_data=list(random.sample(l,len(l)))

figure_canvas_agg = None

while True:
    event, value = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'Draw':
        if figure_canvas_agg is not None:
            figure_canvas_agg.clear()
        figure_canvas_agg = draw_figure(window['canvas1'].TKCanvas, drawBars(x_data,y_data,'red','plot'))
    if event == 'Delete':
        if figure_canvas_agg is not None:
            figure_canvas_agg.clear()
window.close()
```

### Explanation of changes

1. Added a global variable `figure_canvas_agg` to store the `FigureCanvasTkAgg` object.
2. In the `Draw` event, check if the `figure_canvas_agg` is not `None`. If it is not `None`, call the `clear` method of the `FigureCanvasTkAgg` object.
3. In the `Delete` event, check if the `figure_canvas_agg` is not `None`. If it is not `None`, call the `clear` method of the `FigureCanvasTkAgg` object.

Comment: i put that in then i got the following error: AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasTkAgg' object has no attribute 'clear'